# How to delete specific characters from a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, trim

I have several strings that look like this:

```
"((String1))"
```

They are all different lengths. How could I remove the parentheses from all these strings in a loop?

Comment: Remove parentheses, or remove first two and last two characters from a "random" string? (Actually random?)

Comment: "((String1))"[2...-2] # => "String1"

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html

Comment: You are asking for a loop to change many string, how are the strings stored?

Comment: I know how to make a loop through all the strings i just wanted the string manipulation part, sorry i worded that weird

Comment: Here's a solution a chef might like: `def chop_chop(s) chop_one_way(chop_one_way(s,')').reverse,'(').reverse end` and
`def chop_one_way(s,c); s.chop! while s[-1] == c; s; end
chop_chop "(((abc)))" # => "abc"`.

Answer (score 197, accepted):

Do as below using [`String#tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-tr) :

```
 "((String1))".tr('()', '')
 # => "String1"
```

Comment: There's also a destructive version `tr!` that will modify a string in-place, like `my_string.tr!(')(','')`

Comment: Note that this function is not trimming from the beginning or end, but a full replacement on all text within the string.

Comment: Misleading and incorrect. Tr is not a trimming function, it is a replacement function. The two are very different operations.

Comment: @ZaneClaes Yes. OP used wrong term to explain what actually the OP wants. The answer has shown how to achieve the output.

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tr'

Comment: @NathanB Ruby version?

Answer (score 49):

If you just want to remove the first two characters and the last two, then you can use [negative indexes](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) on the string:

```
s = "((String1))"
s = s[2...-2]
p s # => "String1"
```

If you want to remove all parentheses from the string you can use the [delete](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-delete) method on the string class:

```
s = "((String1))"
s.delete! '()'
p s #  => "String1"
```

Comment: This will delete all parentheses, even those in the middle of the string as well, which (seemingly) is not what OP wants. If that is what is wanted this is the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 30):

For those coming across this and looking for performance, it looks like `#delete` and `#tr` are about the same in speed and 2-4x faster than `gsub`.

```
text = "Here is a string with / some forwa/rd slashes"
tr = Benchmark.measure { 10000.times { text.tr('/', '') } }
# tr.total => 0.01
delete = Benchmark.measure { 10000.times { text.delete('/') } }
# delete.total => 0.01
gsub = Benchmark.measure { 10000.times { text.gsub('/', '') } }
# gsub.total => 0.02 - 0.04
```

Comment: Four years later... :-) I find if I up your benchmarking by a couple orders of magnitude (1_000_000 runs), that with the same code you use above, I do get delete running slightly faster than tr, with delete at about a 0.92 ratio of tr, and gsub a little less than 1.5x of delete (actually ~ 1.46 of delete, and ~ 1.39 of tr). ymmv of course. This is on Ruby 2.6.3 on a 2018 MBP 13. Thanks for benchmarking these three methods!

Answer (score 23):

Using [`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) with regular expression:

```
"((String1))".gsub(/^\(+|\)+$/, '')
# => "String1"
"(((((( parentheses )))".gsub(/^\(+|\)+$/, '')
# => " parentheses "
```

This will remove surrounding parentheses only.

```
"(((((( This (is) string )))".gsub(/^\(+|\)+$/, '')
# => " This (is) string "
```

Comment: +1 for the second example (remove surrounding parentheses only).

Answer (score 2):

Use [String#delete](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#method-i-delete):

```
"((String1))".delete "()"
=> "String1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an even shorter way of achieving this:

1) using `Negative character class pattern matching`

```
irb(main)> "((String1))"[/[^()]+/]
=> "String1"
```

`^` - Matches anything NOT in the character class. Inside the charachter class, we have `(` and `)`

Or with global substitution "AKA: gsub" like others have mentioned.

```
irb(main)> "((String1))".gsub(/[)(]/, '')
=> "String1"
```

Comment: Your two answers have different results on `((a))b`. The first will only return `a`, the second will return `ab`