# Ruby on Rails - Remove/Replace some characters in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, nested-forms

I use `nested_form` along with **bootstrap tab**. To making *bootstrap tab* work properly I need to give each tab a *unique* id, otherwise only one of the 4 tabs will work correctly.

I have been able to get the `id` of each nested form input and give it as a *unique id* to each tab by using this:

```
- field_title = f.text_field :title
- id2 = field_title.match(/id="(?<id>[^"]*)"/)
```

In my *bootstrap tab* I have used this solution:

```
.nav-tabs-custom
  %ul.nav.nav-tabs
    %li.active
      %a{"data-toggle" => "tab", :href => "#tab_1_upl_#{id2}"} Upload
    %li
      %a{"data-toggle" => "tab", :href => "#tab_2_url_#{id2}"} link
    %li
      %a{"data-toggle" => "tab", :href => "#tab_3_lib_#{id2}"} image library

  .tab-content
    %div{id: "tab_1_upl_""#{id2}", class: " tab-pane active"}
      image

    %div{id: "tab_2_url_""#{id2}", class: " tab-pane"}
      link

    %div{id: "tab_3_lib_""#{id2}", class: " tab-pane"}
      library
```

But the issue now is that, the `id` for anchor is like:

`id=" #tab_2_url_id="table_choices_attributes_1464338477560_title" "`

As you can see this part: `="table_choices_attributes_1464338477560_title"` is the issue here and prevent the *tab* to work properly.

How can I only get the *text* inside the `id` or just replace `= "`?

I have tried with `gsub`, `tr`, `tr!` and getting error `undefined method`.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Tried this ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19637677/ruby-remove-characters-from-a-string

Comment: yes, and I get error `undefined method "tr"`. I tried this: `id2 = field_title.match(/id="(?<id>[^"]*)"/).tr("=", '')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tr` or `gsub` can not be used with a variable. So what I did was to use it *outside* of the string like code blow:

```
%div{id: "tab_1_upl_""#{id2}".tr('"=', ''), class: " tab-pane active"}
```